# Loading message during template redraw in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I built my first Meteor app and I love it. Except, now that it has real production data in it, it's a little slow. I'm getting reports that "nothing is happening when I click this".

**Is there any way to display a loading message during template redraws so that the user knows something is happening?**

To illustrate further, look at this template (not my actual code, for simplicity only):

```
Template.all_posts.posts = function() {
  return Posts.find({'category_id': Session.get('current_category')});
}
```

So if open my console and run `Session.set('current_category', 1)`, and let's say it takes 2 seconds to run the computation and redraw the templates. I'd like there to display a loading indicator during that 2 second period.

To be clear, I already know how to display a loading indicator. In fact, I'm already do that on initial page load and hiding it when all my subscriptions are `ready()`. I simply want to know where to apply that same logic (showing and hiding loading icon) so that it will happen every time the templates are redrawn. Pseudo code would work fine:

**In short, when Meteor is busy, I want to reflect that.**

Any help is greatly appreciated!

**Edit 10/09/13:**

From the docs...

> These Meteor functions run your code as a reactive computation:
>
> - Templates
> - Meteor.render and Meteor.renderList
> - Deps.autorun

I think one possible solution could *begin* with displaying a loading indicator when any of these "computations" are invalidated.

For example, if you're code is being run inside of `Deps.autorun`, the computation instance is passed as the first argument and you can pass a callback to it's `onInvalidate` method, like so:

```
Deps.autorun(function(computation) {

  // do reactive stuff

  computation.onInvalidate(function() {
    // display loading indicator
  });
});
```

However, to my knowledge, you cannot access the computation object in those other Meteor methods, only `Deps.autorun`.

As far as hiding the loading indicator, I think the best idea would be to do it *inside the `rendered` callback of the last template to be (re)rendered* due to the invalidation of the computation.

**Anyone have any insights, suggestions, tricks, hacks, etc. into this?**

Comment: Can you give a more representative example of what you're doing?  Perhaps a small repro on github that illustrates the problem?

Comment: @alanning Any of the Meteor examples would do fine. Basically, I want to show a loading message when ANY computation is invalidated and hide it when the last template is finished (re)rendering.

Comment: Template loading indicator... seems like you'd need to patch Spark to call hooks on invalidate.  But Spark is getting rewritten so wouldn't be useful for long.  

There may be something that can be done to improve the speed of your app enough to not need it.  In general, rendering should be fairly instantaneous.  If its not there may be an opportunity to refactor the design a bit.

Comment: @alanning Spark patch... That's what I was thinking, but would that include everything, including the computation? Or just the template rendering? Probably right about making it faster. It *is* my first Meteor app. I'm slowly improving the performance of it little by little. Unfortunately my app is running in a browser shell of another application, to which I don't have source access, and it uses the IE7 rendering engine. But it's still fairly slow when I run inside Chrome so I'll stay at it.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly use `Template.myTemplate.created = function ( ) { ... }`, as mentioned in the [meteor documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#template_created). You might be able run some jQuery on the creation of the template, and add a loading class to the body, and then on `Template.myTemplate.rendered`, remove the loading class?

Comment: According to (my interpretation of) the docs, that would only work the first time it was rendered, not on rerenders. "_This callback is called when an invocation of myTemplate represents a new occurrence of the template and not a re-rendering of an existing template instance._"

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you never solved this problem, I'd like to share another user's solution that he posted as part of an answer to [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313191/meteor-each-in-template-loads-old-data-first-then-reloads/22313556?noredirect=1#22313556).  Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22313556/354065) by nate-strauser:

> hook into the .ready() method of the collection to determine when you can show it. this will return true when all data is loaded on the client. you are seeing empty, then partial, then full rendering because your code isn't waiting for all data and is rendering as data arrives. this isn't a bad thing, but not always desirable. you can roll your own solution using something like https://github.com/oortcloud/unofficial-meteor-faq#how-do-i-know-when-my-subscription-is-ready-and-not-still-loading , but i would recommend using iron-router with the waitOn function for the route in question https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router#waiting-on-subscriptions-waiton, when this is used in combination with the loadingTemplate option you can make a nice (Loading....) message while loading, then transition right away to the fully populated template

You can ignore the full-partial part.

Comment: This problem is still unsolved. The `ready` method only helps during the time that a collection is initially loading and doesn't help with future template redraws and computation invalidations. As stated in my original question, I'm already using `ready`. Thanks!