# Meteor - {{#each}} in template loads old data first, then reloads

Tags: javascript, performance, mongodb, templates, meteor

I have a Meteor application at gnf.meteor.com for donation campaigns in a program being run by my family's shop.  The application itself is not too relevant to this question, but it provides simple credit card checkouts which hook into paypal, and keeps track of the resulting transaction logs and balances for us.

The page in my application relevant to this question is https://gnf.meteor.com/log.  This page is a log of the latest donations on the site, their donors, types, amounts and recipients.

When you first load or reload the page at /log, Meteor takes a solid 7-10 seconds before it renders the correct data.  During this interval, it first displays an empty list, then after a few seconds it will show some older records (not the latest data) and then finally it will re-render with the correct records.  I'm guessing that maybe the collection gets rendered, then sorted, then re-rendered, but I can't tell if it's truly a sorting issue and it might just be loading old records first, rendering before it's done loading.

To demonstrate what I mean, load the page and observe that the latest donation (top of the list) at the time of this writing should be "Maura M. $70 -> Suzie Murphy".  (This application is not being used heavily yet, so that will remain the latest transaction for a while.)

I'd like to avoid this if possible, and I'm also planning to introduce a loading message as desired by the asker of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254929/loading-message-during-template-redraw-in-meteor).

I also hate that it takes so long to load in the first place, even though there are only about 300 records in my transactions collection.  Maybe I can achieve the same query in a more efficient way somehow?

Here is the relevant code from my application:

in my Javascript:

```
Data = {
  funds         : new Meteor.Collection('funds'),
  transactions  : new Meteor.Collection('transactions')
};

// ...

Template.logPage.latestDonations = function() {
  return Data.transactions.find({
    $or : [{ type : 'donation' }, { type : 'deposit' }]
  }, {
    sort : { timestamp : -1 },
    limit : 50
  });
};

Template.logPage.typeDonation = function() {
  return this.type == "donation";
};

Template.logPage.typeDeposit = function() {
  return this.type == "deposit";
};
```

in my HTML:

```
<template name="logPage">
  <h1 class="underline">Latest 50 Donations <small>(updates in real time)</small>&nbsp;&nbsp;</h1>
    {{#each latestDonations}}
        <h2>
            {{donorName}} &nbsp;
            {{#if typeDonation}}
                <i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i>
            {{/if}}
            {{#if typeDeposit}}
                <i class="fa fa-money"></i>
            {{/if}}
            &nbsp;${{amount}}&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
            &nbsp; <a href="/fund/{{fund_id}}">{{recipientName}}</a>
            <small><abbr class="timeago" title="{{donationTimestamp}}">
                {{donationTimeString}}</abbr>
            </small>
        </h2>
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

Thanks in advance for any insight anyone might have.  Meteor is great, but these little annoyances frustrate me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a couple suggestions for your problem

1) edit your server side publish function (i'm assuming you have this and are not using the autopublish package) to only publish 50 using the timestamp to sort.  this will send less data to the client and only the data you actually are going to use.  you just have to move your find query to the server where you likely have a find query without any attributes `.find({})`

2) hook into the `.ready()` method of the collection to determine when you can show it.  this will return true when all data is loaded on the client.  you are seeing empty, then partial, then full rendering because your code isn't waiting for all data and is rendering as data arrives.  this isn't a bad thing, but not always desirable.  you can roll your own solution using something like https://github.com/oortcloud/unofficial-meteor-faq#how-do-i-know-when-my-subscription-is-ready-and-not-still-loading , but i would recommend using iron-router with the waitOn function for the route in question https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router#waiting-on-subscriptions-waiton, when this is used in combination with the `loadingTemplate` option you can make a nice (Loading....) message while loading, then transition right away to the fully populated template

Comment: Thanks so much!  I am already using iron-router, so I'll definitely us the waitOn function, I hadn't known about that.

Comment: As for changing my publish function, how does that work with respect to different views?  I need to have the whole collection published for other pages which display, i.e. the entire transaction history of a fund.  Can I both publish all of the collection to one template and some of the collection to another template?

Comment: yes, exactly - just name the publications differently - you can have multiple publications of the same collection and meteor will merge them client side - a popular pattern would have 2 publications like `recentTransactions`(last 50) and `fundDetails` (the fund + all transactions for this fund - see http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_publish for returning 2+ query results from collections in 1 publish) - to optimize even further you can use the `fields` attribute to only send down just what you need for each publication - you can then attach each publication to a specific template/route

Comment: Ok great!  Sorry, I'm still learning meteor.  How do I go about attaching a specific publication to a route?

Comment: use `waitOn` to attach the subscription then use `data` to return the results from the query - see https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router#data